# Wrong time now (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, time, timezone, timestamp

I have a problem in relation with the time now in Codeigniter.
I'm using the **timespan** function in codeigniter. I have to get the current time and it returns a wrong current time now. My date in my pc(as of now) is 2013-07-04 3:21 PM but when I do this:

```
$now = time(); 
$human = unix_to_human($now);
echo $human;
```

The output is 2013-07-05 12:20 AM. Why is that?

Comment: Try echoing `date_default_timezone_get()` and see what time zone php thinks your in.

Comment: It is giving the server time

Comment: @Jeemusu it echoes Europe/Berlin, I've tried changing the timezone in my pc settings but it still shows Europe/Berlin.

Comment: I also tried @user1795109's code but to no avail.

Comment: It's not a problem with your pc settings, but most likely your php.ini or timezones.ini if you have one. You could change it there, or alternatively you could include `date_default_timezone_set('WRITE YOUR TIME ZONE HERE');` in one of your constructs or index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place this code at the top of your index.php (bootstrap file).

```
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
}
```

instead of 'Asia/Dhaka' use your own time zone. should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

It return the web server time, not your pc time. Try setting the time zone to your location.

Comment: Did you used this function date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
copy the function in Codeingiter index.php file and change the timezone location

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this in CodeIgniter with a Helper class like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use CodeIgniter\I18n\Time;

class DateHelper {

    public static function getTime($dateString = 'now'){
        
        $time = new Time($dateString);
        if(!$time->getDst()){
            $time = $time->subHours(1);
        }
        return $time;
    }

    public static function getNowString(){
        return static::getTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

}
```

I basically use this function:

```php
    /**
     * ( function from CodeIgniter\I18n\Time )
     * Are we in daylight savings time currently?
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getDst(): bool
```

To check if we are currently in daylight savings time,
if so I subtract 1 hour . This works for me, my timezone is Europe/Lisbon which is being used by default because I've configured it in app/config/App.php by changing the following variable:

```php
 public $appTimezone = 'Europe/Lisbon';.
```